# Cannot assign 'CommandManagerBinding' into property 'Command', type must be assignable to 'ICommand'

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, catel

I want to use [Catel's application-wide commands](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Application-wide+commands) in the Windows Store app. At compile time I am getting an error:

> Cannot assign 'CommandManagerBinding' into property 'Command', type
>   must be assignable to 'ICommand'

I wonder if this Catel's feature actually supported in Windows Runtime?

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, custom bindings classes are not supported in WinRT. To use it, put the command on the view model (you can retrieve it from the ICommandManager in your view model) and bind to it.

It's unfortunate that this is a limitation of the Windows RT platform. For me it's like this:

WPF > Silverlight > Phone (SL) > Windows RT

I think the CommandManagerBinding is currently only supported in WPF and SL.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot put the command in the view model :( The problem is that I need to execute the command from the ItemTemplate. The ItemsControl's ItemsSource binds to the property of the view model thus in DataTemplate I have a different DataContext (a member of ItemsSource collection). So I need either get a parent DataContext (RelativeSource didn't help there) or call some global command. Actually both don’t work.

Comment: You can always create a static class with all the commands (wrapper around ICommandManager) that you can bind to. Not as nice, but Windows RT simply doesn't give many other options.

Comment: x:Static isn't available in WinRT as well. The final working solution was referencing CommandManager as StaticResource. <Button Content="Compare" Command="{Binding CompareCommand, Source={StaticResource CommandManager}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>